# interpret signed as unsigned

Tags: c++

I have a value like this:

```
int64_t s_val = SOME_SIGNED_VALUE;
```

How can I get a

```
uint64_t u_val
```

that has exactly the same bit pattern as `s_val`, but is treated as unsigned?

This may be really simple, but after looking on Stackoverflow and elsewhere I haven't turned up the answer.

Comment: Up votes for everyone; thanks for your input.  I think static_cast is in fact the right answer.  For the record, I had tried it first, but owing to a dunderheaded error elsewhere I thought it was not preserving the bit pattern.  To clarify the question, it's okay that s_val != u_val (which will be the case if s_val < 0).  The bits are what matters.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
int64_t s_val = SOME_SIGNED_VALUE;
uint64_t u_val = static_cast<uint64_t>(s_val);
```

C++ Standard 4.7/2 states that:

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type).  [Note: In a two’s complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation).  ]

From the other hand, Standard says that "The mapping performed by `reinterpret_cast` is implementation-defined.  [Note: it might, or might not, produce a representation different from the original value.  ]" (5.2.10/3). So, I'd recommend to use `static_cast`.

Answer (score 11):

Note that you don't need the cast at all.  For all the wrangling about whether the cast will munge bits or not for negative representations, one thing has gotten lost - the cast is completely unnecessary.

Because of the conversions that C/C++ will do (and how casting is defined), this:

```
int64_t s_val = SOME_SIGNED_VALUE;
uint64_t u_val = s_val;
```

is exactly equivalent to:

```
int64_t s_val = SOME_SIGNED_VALUE;
uint64_t u_val = static_cast<uint64_t>(s_val);
```

That said, you might still want the cast because it signals intent.  However, I've heard it argued that you shouldn't use unnecessary casts because it can silence the compiler in situations where you might *want* a warning.

Pick your poison.

Comment: Aha, that's a good point.  In my case I think it's best to signal intent, but I'm glad to see the caveat.

Answer (score 10):

I agree static_cast is appropriate in this case, but no one has mentioned a very similar looking case where static_cast wouldn't preserve bits as might be expected.

```
char x = -1; // 255
unsigned int x2 = static_cast<unsigned int>(x); // 4294967295
unsigned int x3 = static_cast<unsigned int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(x)); // 255
```

Watch out for [sign extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) when you are casting from a small signed value to a large unsigned value.  Possibly other combinations are vulnerable too - I haven't thought it all the way through.

Comment: Interesting point; thanks for explaining and providing the link to sign extension.

Comment: Note that the second line is allowed to produce `255` as well, because implementations are allowed to make `char` unsigned.

Answer (score 7):

Generally speaking, it doesn't matter whether you use `static_cast<int64_t>` or `reinterpret_cast<int64_t>`. So long as you are running on a processor that uses [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) to represent negative numbers, the result is the same. (Practically all modern processors use that.) Under two's complement, a positive number in a signed int is represented the same way in an unsigned int; if it's a negative number it'll be reinterpreted as a large positive number in the unsigned form.

Basically, what your cast does is tell the compiler to produce different assembly instructions when dealing with that value. E.g. there are different instructions for multiplication and division for signed integers. Although addition and subtraction remains the same (read the wikipedia link and you'll understand).

Comment: But what about a negative value?

Comment: The rule is "if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type", which works for 2's complement, and I think 1's complement, but I wouldn't swear that it kept the same bit pattern for more bizzaro representations of negative numbers.

Comment: The above is from the C99 standard, the C++ standard says this: "the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2n where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [Note: In a two’s complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation). ]"

Comment: I believe almost all processors use the two's complement. But I'll add it in.

Comment: There's no doubt that two's complement is by far the most likely representation used for negative numbers. I personally haven't worked on anything other than two's complement machines except for some Univac (sound like something from a scifi novel) thing back in University. It had 36-bit words to boot.

Comment: Unfortunately for me, until the standard says that integers are represented in 2's compliment the above re-assurance is not good enough. Historically too many programes have been broken by assumptions just like this one that are never again validated when the code is ported to another platform. Then tracing the problem the bug is next to impossable.

Answer (score 6):

Wanted to share this C++14 modern, generic solution. Originally demonstrated [here](https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/13/gotw-93-solution-auto-variables-part-2/).

```
template<class T> 
auto as_unsigned(T t) 
{ 
    return std::make_unsigned_t<T>(t); 
}
```

Which may be used as follows:

```
auto sx = int32_t{ 55 };
auto ux = as_unsigned(sx);
```

You can see it in action [here](http://ideone.com/PzM5o2).

Comment: I would love to have something like this for pointers as well. I currently have to add non-generic overloads for each conversion I need, like `char *` → `uint8_t *`.

Answer (score 5):

Logical bit pattern (bits of value-representation), i.e. values of binary digits can only be preserved if the original signed value was non-negative, because negative values cannot be represented by an unsigned integer variable. All you need to do is to assign your signed value to your unsigned integral object and you are done

```
uint64_t u_val = s_val;
```

An explicit cast is not necessary, but might be used to suppress compiler warnings.

As for physical bit pattern (i.e. what you see in raw memory, bits of object-representation), you simply can't "convert" it that way. C++ language does not provide you with any methods of conversion that would guarantee to preserve the physical bit pattern. All you can do is to *reinterpret* the memory occupied by the signed object as an unsigned object of the same size

```
STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(int64_t) == sizeof(uint64_t));
uint64_t u_val = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t&>(s_val);
```

Again, this is not a conversion, but rather a memory reinterpretation. This is not guaranteed to work and this is generally illegal.

Comment: Good point to distinguish "conversion" from "interpretation"!

Comment: How is it illegal?  What do you mean by 'work'?  You _can_ `reinterpret` back, can't you?

Comment: It is illegal becuse C++ language explcitly prohibits accessing memory occupied by an object of type `T` as an object of different type `U` (with few exceptions). In other words, reading reinterpreted memory is almost always illegal.

Comment: yes, good point about "conversion" and "interpretation."  Title of question now uses correct terminology.

Answer (score 2):

You can also `reinterpret_cast` it, or use a `union`:

```
union {
   int64_t i64;
   uint64_t ui64;
} variable;

variable.i64 = SOME_SIGNED_VALUE;
uint64_t a_copy = variable.ui64;
```

Comment: `static_cast` will not lead to losing bit pattern.

Comment: I was a bit worried about static_cast<>. I was also going to suggest using reinterpret_cast<> becuase of the bit pattern statement. Are you sure static_cast<> will work (I think it will but dont have a copy of the standard handy). But reinterpret_cast<> is also an indication that it is an unsafe cast.

Comment: @Martin: the unsafety is probably understood since he's concerned about the bits, not the value.

Comment: 4.7/2 "<...>In a two’s complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern". `static_cast` uses conversion from 4.7/2.

Comment: Confusion on this exact issue is why I like to cast references instead.